# Can someone show the proof of the ideal test?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have just began studying ideals and came across the ideal test. The text says that we can apply a subgroup test and the subring test but I  uncertain how to start and proceed. Can someone show me this proof?

Comment: what test are you talking about?

Comment: @brick the ideal test.

Comment: You make me to repeat my question! What do you want exactly to prove???

Comment: @brick the ideal test is a theorem. That is what I am trying to prove. Is the question not clear?

Comment: pff what is the theorem man????

Comment: The theorem is the theorem in our course which we call ideal test :D :v

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a ring and $S$ a subset. Then $S$ is by definition an ideal if

1) $S$ is a subgroup of the underlying additive group of $R$.

2) If $r \in R$ and $s \in S$, then $rs, sr \in S$.

To show that $S$ is an ideal, you simply show that these two conditions hold. Apply an appropriate subgroup test to show the first one. For instance, if $S$ is non-empty and for all $x,y \in S$, we have $x-y \in S$, then $S$ is a subgroup.